# How to rearrange the columns in a 2d array matrix alphabetically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to take the following matrix below and rearrange  the chars TOAD to ADOT and the rearrange the corresponding columns below to where the char above moved, so for example A moved to col 0 so now VGD should all be in col 0 etc.

TOAD is a separate array by the way! im using that keyword to sort the martrix alphabetically.

```
//Matrix output and then the code.
        T O A D 
        V V V X 
        D V G G 
        D F D V 


public String printMatrix(String s [][]){
        char key[] = polyCipher.getKeyword().toCharArray();
        String keyOut = "";
        for(int i=0;i<key.length;i++){
            keyOut += key[i] + " ";
        }
        keyOut += "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
       //     keyOut += PHRASE_KEY[i] + " ";
           for (int j = 0; j < s[i].length; j++) {
                keyOut += s[i][j] + " ";
            }
            keyOut += "\n";
        }
        return keyOut.toUpperCase();
    }

    public static String [][] buildMatrix (String translation, String outermarker, String innermarker) {
        // outerdelim may be a group of characters
        String [] sOuter = translation.split("[" + outermarker + "]"); 
        int size = sOuter.length;
        // one dimension of the array has to be known on declaration:
        String [][] result = new String [size][size]; 
        int count = 0;
        for (String line : sOuter)
        {
            result [count] = line.split (innermarker);
            ++count;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void sortArray(){
        // do tomorrow
    }

    public String matrixFormatter(String x){

         String resultstr = "";
          int i = 0;
          while(i < x.length()) {
            // If end of string: only add character.
            if (i == x.length() - 1) {
              resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1);
            } else {
              if ( ((i + 1) % 4) == 0) {
                resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1)  + "|";
              } else {
                resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1)  + ",";
              }
            }
            i++;
          }
          return resultstr;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you sort (alphabetically or otherwise) the indexes of the characters TOAD? In your example it would look like [2, 3, 0, 1]. Then you can create a new array in a for loop that does something like new_array[i][j] = old_array[sorted[i]][j]

Comment: I think I understand where your coming from so yea ill try that